# How to translate variables in Jinja2/Django

Tags: django, jinja2, django-i18n

I use i18n in my Jinja2 templates and everything works fine for plain text.
But I can't find any info how to use translations with variables, which I can't avoid using. Here is an example:

```
{% set words = ["Hello", "world"] %}

{% for word in words %}
  {{ _(word) }}
{% endfor %}
```

What should I do to get "Hello" and "world" in my .po file?

Comment: Is it obligatory to translate them inside the template? How about translate them inside your view?

Comment: @nik_m yep it was. I posted solution

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I needed to use Babel for jinja2:
http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/integration/

Posting here, because someone can be in the same trouble